# Makefile execution steps does not print in terminal if file is executed from a tcl file

Tags: tcl, exec

```
proc buildMirus { } {
    exec ./autogrn.sh
    if { [catch { exec make -j 6 }] } { /* make should give execution steps on terminal but it's not happening*/
        puts "Error occured while building"
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Tcl's `exec` command defaults to consuming the `stdout` of the subprocess to be the normal result of the `exec`, and to consuming the `stderr` of the subprocess to be the message of an error thrown by `exec` (if it exists). This is very convenient for many uses, but not what you want here, where you want to let the input and output go directly from/to the user and just handle any error codes. You can do this by adding some redirects, specifically:

```
if { [catch { exec make -j 6 <@stdin >@stdout 2>@stderr }] } {
```

`<@stdin` says "take input from the `stdin` channel", `>@stdout` says "send normal output to the `stdout` channel", and `2>@stderr` says "send error output to the `stderr` channel".

Comment: If you want to also do processing on the output, you might need to use the Expect package/program. It's powerful, but potentially quite complicated and definitely very specific to exactly what code you are running...